# CollapsingToolbar not collapsing in one of the fragment of viewpager

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I Have added Collapsing toolbar and I am using view pager which collapse the toolbar when I scroll up.
View pager have some fragments which contains recyclerview and some contains  constraint layout with no recyclerview.
So the problem is fragment of **viewpager which doesn't contain recyclerview** **having a problem of collapsing the toolbar** whereas those **fragments who contains recyclerview doesn't have any problem in collapsing the toolbar**.

Now I am adding the code of my layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/posterbackdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="none" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/posterbackdrop" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleMarginTop="15dp" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            style="@style/MyTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:theme="@style/TabLayout_Theme"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/TextColor"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white" />
        <abcd.com.tmdb.Common.FontTypeFace
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:transitionName="moviename"
            app:typeface="roboto_bold" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution for this problem by adding NestedScrollView on the constraint layout of the view pager fragment make the toolbar collapse.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Yes It says 48 hours later :)

Comment: Please do it later if possible

Comment: Yeah sure if it helped you somehow then you can also accept it

Comment: Only author can accept an answer to his question. Others can upvote though